Help needed in identifying part of the sentence

It made Ruby's heart melt.

How would I label melt if I were parsing the sentence? At first I thought melt was an object compliment adjective, but now I'm wondering if it is part of a noun clause acting as a direct object. Any ideas?

In the sentence "It made Ruby's heart melt", made is a catenative verb and melt is its catenative complement. The catenative complement is a clause, which in this case is just a bare infinitive.
A Student's Introduction to English Grammar (p216) classifies such sentences as "complex catenative constructions" as there is a noun phrase (in this case Ruby's heart) between the catenative verb  and its complement.
In contrast, there is nothing intervening between the catenative verb and its complement in "simple catenative constructions" such as "Max regrets locking the door", where regrets is the catenative verb and locking the door is the catenative complement.

I vote for this because it is formally accurate. Nevertheless it raises the question for me of whether grammar is prescriptive of forms of expression or merely descriptive of them.

@Anton. The Student's Introduction to English Grammar is a companion to and written by the same authors as of the Cambridge Grammar of the English Language, which is a descriptive reference work. It goes into much more detail on catenative constructions.

So how would that sentence be diagrammed?

Also, if there is an indirect object in this sentence, does that not break the catenate chain?

@ishtar has provided one way that the sentence can be diagrammed. As to your other question, perhaps you could amend the sentence to include an indirect object in the chain. Or provide a different sentence with that pattern. I can't envisage one off the top of my head.
